# Need to modify the existing 'default' connection in cakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to modify the existing `'default'` connection.
I tried to write it like this:-

```
ConnectionManager::config('default',$consoptions);
```

It gives an error telling me that we cannot reconfigure existing key `"default"`.
Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

The [example shown in the CakePHP Cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#quick-tour) is wrong and causes the error

> Cannot reconfigure existing key "default"

You actually need to drop the default database connection configuration before replacing it with a new one.

In addition, the `ConnectionManager::config()` methos is deprecated in favour of `ConnectionManager::setConfig()`

This is a working example that modifies the default database connection:

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

$dsn = 'mysql://root:password@localhost/my_database';

ConnectionManager::drop('default');
ConnectionManager::config('default', ['url' => $dsn]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> It gives an error telling me that we cannot reconfigure existing key "default" Is there any way to achieve what I want?

[Drop the config](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Datasource.ConnectionManager.html#_drop) then configure it again.

Spend some time checking the API, it's almost all there.