# Error Cannot reconfigure existing key "excel"

Tags: cakephp

I tried to do a cake i18n extract and i got this error.

```
Exception: Cannot reconfigure existing key "excel" in [C:\wamp64\www\boyma2\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Core\StaticConfigTrait.php, line 88]
```

I don't know why that mistake comes out and now he doesn't let me make a cake bake all

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are setting "excel" key configuration value again. Please refer to this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503939/need-to-modify-the-existing-default-connection-in-cakephp-3).